# Консольные скрипты в symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2, консоль, symfony, процесс

Имеется:

1. консольный скрипт в symfony2, запускаемый по крону (класс-наследник `ContainerAwareCommand`)
2. очередь (в redis) содержащая `id` объектов с которыми надо совершить некое действие

Как в консольной команде symfony2 проверить, что эта команда не выполняется другим процессом в данный момент?

Есть общепринятый вариант: сохранить куда-нибудь `pid` процесса и при запуске команды, проверить статус процесса с этим `pid`.

Однако я считаю что в symfony2 должен быть уже готовый метод для этой цели, просто я его ещё не нашёл в документации.

Comment: В симфонии такого готового метода нет, можно только получить пид запускаемого процесса при его запуске.

Comment: У вас же есть редис, пишите прямо в него. `SETNX %command%:%job-id%:lock` - и, благодаря однопоточности, захватить лок может только один исполнитель. Я уж молчу про то, что внутри есть и очереди, и pub/sub.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html):

```
# cron example
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /var/lock/command_name.lock -c "/path_to_symfony/app/console console:commmand --arguments"
```

Это простой и надёжный способ избежать второго вызова команды, пока не завершился первый.